# Backslash in HTTP response message

Tags: c#, .net

I'm returning following Json string through HttpResponseMessage from my method:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent("{\"response\":[{\"code\":\"1\",\"description\":\"Happy\"}]}",Encoding.UTF8,"application/json") };
```

And reading body of `HttpResponseMessage` as follow:

`var responseBody = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`;

I was expecting following string in output :

```
{"response":[{"code":"1","description":"Happy"}
```

But the result I got is:

```
{\"response\":[{\"code\":\"1\",\"description\":\"Happy\"}
```

I also tried using, 
`var responseBody = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());` but still getting the same result.

Comment: Where is this string shown? In your debugger's variable window?

Comment: Are you sure the string is actually like this and that you are not looking at debugger values?

Comment: Indeed, my guess is that you're looking in the debugging, which escapes strings for you (unhelpfully, IMO). Print the string out to a console (or log)

Comment: I've tried your sample and it works correct and not as the output you've shown, perhaps as @JonSkeet suggested it has something to do with your debugger or IMO a possible bug in server part. Complete response ** <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"response":[{"code":"1","description":"Happy"}]}</pre> **

Comment: @UweKeim,  I'm getting the string in postman response when I hit post request. During debugging when I view string in Text Viewer It's correct without backslash.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm getting the string with backslash in post request from postman along with 200 OK

Comment: That sounds very odd, but I'd avoid Postman as well here - you're making a request from .NET, so do that and print out the result from .NET as well. Just write it to the console.

Comment: @JonSkeet  public class Program
    {
        public static async void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var response = getHttpResponse();
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
        }
        
        public static HttpResponseMessage getHttpResponse()
        {
            var s1 = "{\"Hello\":\"Message\"}";
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent(s1,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json") };
        }
    }  I get {"Hello":"Message"} in this

Comment: Please don't include code in comments - it's unreadable, and as the *sole* content of the comment, it doesn't help explain anything anyway. Instead, edit your question to give more information.

Comment: Sure @JonSkeet !